How to merge billing export tables in GCP BigQuery
I'm trying to merge two billing export tables in GCP BigQuery into a single table. Each table is partitioned by _PARTITIONTIME.
I attempted to perform a bulk data load from one table into the other using an LOAD query, but after a few minutes, the data disappears without any error or log indication.
Is there a reliable way to transfer data from the old table to the new one without the risk of it being deleted or overwritten? Ideally, I want to preserve both the existing data in the new table and the partitions from the old table.
I don't want to use 'UNION ALL'.
Any advice or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to perform a bulk data load from one table into the other using an LOAD query, but after a few minutes, the data disappears without any error or log indication.
I expect to see the data inside the new table, and not be deleted after several min.

Why do you want to duplicate the data? Which advantage?

Hey, yes.
I want to duplicate the data.
The company created one more billing account. I have many Looker Studio dashboards, and the old large table is connected to several third-party services.
So yes, I need to copy all the data to the third-party services and set up a scheduled query to transfer the data from each day.

Unfortunately, based on the official documentation, this is not possible. Thank you, everyone, for your input!
enter image description here
